# Objective C Seg Fault that only occurs when compiler optimizations are enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, compiler-construction, optimization

I'm stumped trying to debug an issue on iOS that seems to only occur with Release builds which seems to implicate that the optimizer is doing something that isn't playing nicely with my code.  The code that crashes is some code that is serializing some binary data into a NSMutableData instance as follows.

```
[_data increaseLengthBy:sizeof(CFSwappedFloat64)];
*((CFSwappedFloat64 *)[self pointerAtOffset]) = CFConvertFloat64HostToSwapped(value);
_offset += sizeof(CFSwappedFloat64);
```

_data is a NSMutableData instance.  pointerAtOffset and the init method for this class is defined as follows.

```
- (unsigned char *)pointerAtOffset {   
    return ((unsigned char *)_data.mutableBytes) + _offset;
}

- (id)init {
    if( self = [super init] ) {
        _data   = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:1028];
        _offset = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now the strange thing is that if I add a NSLog print statement, it fixes the bug.

```
[_data increaseLengthBy:sizeof(CFSwappedFloat64)];
NSLog(@"%d - %d", (int)_data.mutableBytes, _offset);
*((CFSwappedFloat64 *)[self pointerAtOffset]) = CFConvertFloat64HostToSwapped(value);
_offset += sizeof(CFSwappedFloat64);
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?  It's kind of unnerving to deploy code that works because of a NSLog statement.

Comment: Don't know if it's worth noting that if I copy the implementation of pointerAtOffset inline, it also seems to not crash.

Comment: I looks like the optimiser can't see that `increaseLengthBy:` and `pointerAtOffset` both reference `_offset`, so it moves the calls around. Is there a way (`#pragma`?) to lower the optimisation level locally or force the proper call sequence? Otherwise you can do it for the whole file until you find a better solution. The NSLog call forces this order, which is why it works when it is left in.

Comment: Are you using ARC? It's possible _data is being released automatically before you use the pointer.

Comment: Not using ARC.  The key to making it not crash seems to be accessing the `_offset` variable in the method in any way prior to calling `pointerAtOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the armv6 Thumb instruction problems.  If you change your debug build settings to optimize to Fastest,Smallest and it crashes, then that is your problem.